# Extend existing independent WatchOS app with iOS app and share data between them

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, xcode13, data-sharing

First of all, I'm a newby and I'm sorry if this question is already answered. I searched and I didn't found any similar.

I already have and independent WachOS app and works fine by itself. At firs I thought that with it alone will be enough but now I realized that with an equivalent iOS app I could reach more people. So now I'm wondering if it's possible to modify my Xcode project in order to add an iOS app with the same content and functionality as I have in the WatchOS app and both of them sharing the same data, that is, if I change a value in one of them, later I will see this value updated in the other one.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you already uploaded the app to the AppStore then I'm afraid it's not possible. Source: [Reverting from an Independent Watch app, to one that is dependent on an iPhone app](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/130351)